# Target blank with different domain in a href jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and I've looked at documentation, but I can not make a script that will give me a blank target when I click on the "href" link and it does not contain the domain parameter of a given variable

My pseudocode (because my code is terrible wrong, and maybe my pseudocode  also)

```
var mydomain = "domain.com"
jquery.ready(

    $jquery.function('click', 'ahref?'. e){
        e.src #contanin mydomain#

        window.open('e.src', '_blank');
        return false;
    }
)
```

Comment: `window.open(e.src, '_blank');` without quotes work? where're the errors?

Comment: @Roy numerous other problems in the code shown than just that

Comment: @charlietfl yes, just becouse is "pseudocode"

Comment: But if you dont tell me what kind of errors you have, i never be able to help you.

Comment: Make a online https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip `window.open` by simply adding attribute `target="_blank"` to external links.

You can filter the external links by comparing their `hostname` to the `window.location.hostname`

```
// inside ready block
$('a').filter(function(){
  return this.hostname !== location.hostname
}).attr('target','_blank')
```

Comment: But if i want to change a variable every time i must change x.hostname? thinking x = variable?

Comment: Are you running this on a page with different domain  than the domain in variable?

Comment: Yes becouse i want it

Comment: Then do string comparison to `this.hostname` instead using your variable rather than `location`

Comment: Could even be a simple `===` ... look at what `this.hostname` produces

Comment: this.hostname no produces anything. But location.hostname produces my domain name

Comment: try look at `this.host` also

Comment: undefined thats meaby becouse im localhost?

Comment: Do you have `href` on `<a>`? Something doesn't sound right. I have no problem accessing hostname or host properties myself

Comment: Or maybe using arrow functions which have no `this`?